# How to subselect based on multiple column key

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with a legacy database that uses a three column key for products. I want to select all products that have a status of 'A' or that have a matching record in a second table. If it were a single column primary key (like 'id'), I would do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `product` 
WHERE `status` = 'A'
       OR `id` IN (SELECT `foreign_key` FROM `table2`)
```

I can't figure out how to do the IN-clause subselect with three keys though. I suppose I can concatenate the keys together and compare the strings, but that seems horribly inefficient. Is there a way to do this without concatenation?

Comment: You could use `EXISTS (correlated subquery here)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can LEFT JOIN table product and table2 on the composite key, then `status = 'A' OR table2.id IS NOT NULL`

A LEFT [OUTER] JOIN can be faster than an equivalent subquery because the server might be able to optimize it better

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM product p1
WHERE status = 'A'
   OR EXISTS (SELECT *
     FROM table2 t2
     WHERE t2.id = p1.foreign_key
     AND t2.other_key = p1.secret_key
     ...
     );
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a left join :)

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on p.key1 = t2.key1 and p.key2 = t2.key2 and p.key3 = t2.key3
WHERE status = 'A' OR t2.key1 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UNION:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   'product' 
WHERE  'status' = 'A'
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM   'product' 
       JOIN 'table2' 
       ON (product.id = table2.foreign_key 
       AND ...)
```